# Why does make install not update my symlinks?

Tags: linux, unix, symbolic-link, make

**DEAR FUTURE PEOPLE: When this happens, try adding --prefix=/usr/ or --prefix/usr/bin/ to the end of the command to invoke the config script.**

**I thought that the entire point of including a configuration script was to ensure that things to be installed get installed in the right places, but maybe I'm wrong.**

I'm trying to install a program from source (specifically, the new openSSL). The program seems to install fine, but whenever I type "openssl version -a" it gives me the old version. Most annoyingly, whenever I update through my repo (which is still using 1.0.1f, AKA the Heartbleed version, for some bizarre reason).

It's not just openSSL, a couple of other programs do this too, but sometimes it works fine.

How can I force "make install" to always update my symlinks to the new version? If this is not possible, how do I know which symlinks I need to manually update?

Note: I'm new to the whole Unix/Linux thing. And this website. If I've forgotten to include useful troubleshooting information or have a fundamental misunderstanding of how something works, please let me know.

My steps:

Download tarball through Firefox, use File Roller extract to ~/Downloads

Right click extracted folder, open in Terminal

./config

make (I ran it without sudo the first and second time and it worked, but when I tried to run it a thirs time to create the log file it gave permission errors so I ran i through sudo)

make depend (I don't usually do this, but the console told me to)

sudo make install

Note that for privacy reasons, I have replaced all instances of my user name with $LOGNAME.

Logs are in a .zip folder in this Mediafire link. [link removed by question author]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me 5 days to figure out, but it turns out that the config script for openSSL is borked and it installs to the wrong place. I'm not sure *where* exactly it's been installing, but it's not the right place.

This can be fixed by running `./config --prefix=/usr/`, then redoing `make` and `make install`. The --prefix flag will change the install location to whatever you put after the equals sign.